# Creating a Simple Flow Chart In Beamer Presentation

Tags: beamer, flow-charts

How can I make this type of simple flowchart in `beamer` presentation?

[image]

I am relatively new to LaTeX. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome. There are a lot of packages that allow you to do this such as [TikZ PGF](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

Comment: Search with the key "flowchart" and see if some of the questions and answers that returns are suitable or give you and idea how to draw your flowchart. Then make an attempt to solve the problem, and if you do not succeed, make an MWE that shows us what you have tried so we can help you finalise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution with use of the `forest` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
inner ysep = 2pt,
     align = center,
      grow = south,
% tree      
    anchor = north,
    forked edge,
     l sep = 8mm,
     s sep = 4mm,
  fork sep = 4mm,
            }% end for tree 
[Physical Quantities
    [Scalar Quantities\\
     Some text here
        [\dots]
    ]
    [Vector Quantities\\
     Some text here
        [\dots]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is giving blank output.

Comment: @Mathematics, ups, in editing of my answer I accidentally deleted one `]`. Now corrected.

Answer (score 5):

I think the most simple solution would be the [`forest`-package](https://ctan.org/pkg/forest):

```latex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
[Physical Quantities
    [Scalar Quantities\\
    Some text here,%
    align=center, base=bottom]
    [Vector Quantities\\
    Some text here,%
    align=center, base=bottom]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image: Simple tree diagram]

I hope this helps.